# Scala mongoDB current() method for curent cursor

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am new to scala mongodb my code is

```
while(result.hasNext)
      {    
if(result.next().containsField("profilepic"))
       bl+=result.next().get("profilepic").toString()
}
```

It works for next but what about curr().I Doesn't found any method 
I want something like this

```
bl+=result.curr().get("profilepic").toString()
```

But in scala their is no method such as curr() any alternative?

Comment: I think the library is following the standard iterator pattern. Are you sure it's working. Generally code will look like if(result.hasNext()...

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to Scala, but have much more extensive Java experience.

I guess the problem with your code is that you call `next()` twice while in each iteration of the loop (so you're acting on two elements), while your intent is clearly to act on one.  This code will probably work for you:

```
while(result.hasNext) {
    val curr = result.next
    if(curr.containsField("profilepic")) {
        bl += curr.get("profilepic").toString()
    }
}
```

Read the following section about `Iterator` semantics: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_43.html

The important thing to understand is that each `next` called on an `Iterator` will yield a new element:

```
val result = Iterator("foo", "bar", "baz")
result.next == "foo" // true
result.next == "bar" // true
```

In your case you want to act on the same element several times.  Store it in a variable (e.g. `curr`) and make sure you call `next` exactly once during each iteration.